# State machine workflow in VS 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, workflow-foundation

I have a simple web application (non sharepoint) in which i want to add window workflow. I am using VS 2010 (.Net 4.0). I have done that in VS 2008 but dont know how to create a state machine workflow in VS 2010. The only option i get in creating are 
1. Activity Designer
2. Activity Library
3. WCF Worflow
4. Console

I want that workflow application to be added in my solution so that i can integrate it. Any idea or tutorial would be of great help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The State Machine will be released in late April in the .NET Framework Platform Update 1.

Comment: Please, could you provide a link with information about content of this udpdate? Thanks.

Comment: See Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/18/microsoft-net-framework-4-platform-update-1.aspx

Comment: Included in Update 4.0.3 for Microsoft .NET Framework 4 – Design-time Update for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29054

Answer (score 1):

You could try "Hands-on Labs for Windows® Workflow Foundation in C# and VB.NET". Anyways, there is no State Machine Workflow in the new .Net 4.0 implementation. You can achieve the same end result using the Flowchart.

Comment: How do i make a flowchart in VS 2010 ?

Comment: Open the xaml file containing the Activity and in the Toolbox, there is a TAB called Flowchart ;)

Answer (score 1):

The .Net 4.0 product update 1 has state machine. Check the below link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2478063

Answer (score 1):

State Machines have been added in .NET 4.5 (you can download the [Developer Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms171868%28VS.110%29.aspx#windows_workflow_foundation))

Answer (score 0):

Officially there is no state machine workflow in WF4.0 but you can try first CTP of [State Machine Activity Pack](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/43586).

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264171.aspx

It says,

"There is no longer a state machine activity or workflow model in .NET Framework version 4. For event-driven workflow modeling, see [Flowchart Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489448.aspx)."